# Magnitude and Amplitude in SAR are different?

Tags: sar, insar

**Are these two terms, amplitude and magnitude of radar signal, the same? If they are different what are each one?**

I have been reading some papers and some authors seem to use them interchangeably, while others stick with one along with the whole text.

Comment: Magnitude is not a term typically used within radar. I would refer always to amplitude or intensity (they are related). My assumption here is that these mean the same. Can you provide some examples to give more context?

Comment: Sure, for instance, I am reading Chen and Zebker (2001) [link](https://opg.optica.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-18-2-338), here they use/display magnitude and do not mention amplitude.